# in(F/J)ected plugin в Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, плагин

Привет всем! У меня к вам такой вопрос. Сегодня, лазея по интернету, `GoogleChrome`'ом обнаружил такую вещь. Один его плагин (`Alter Geo`) самовольно добавляет такой код к каждой странице:

```
function injectJs(link) 
{
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.type="text/javascript";
scr.src=link;
scr.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr)
}

injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL('js/injected.js'));
```

А внутри файла injected.js было вот что:

```
var __AlterGeo__Chrome_Ext__ = function()
{

var plugin = null;

this.Init = function()
{
    try
    {
        var emb = document.createElement('embed');
        emb.setAttribute('type', 'application/altergeoproject');
        emb.setAttribute('id', '__altergeo_plugin__');
        emb.setAttribute('width', '0px');
        emb.setAttribute('height', '0px');
        emb.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');

        document.body.appendChild(emb);
        plugin = document.getElementById("__altergeo_plugin__");
    }catch(e){}
}

this.__defineGetter__("doctype", function () {return plugin.doctype});
this.__defineGetter__("sd", function () {return plugin.sd;});
this.__defineGetter__("apikey", function () {return plugin.apikey;});
this.__defineGetter__("uuid", function () {return plugin.uuid;});
this.__defineGetter__("version", function () {return plugin.version;});
this.__defineGetter__("locationprovider", function () {return plugin.locationprovider;});

this.__defineSetter__("doctype", function (value) {return plugin.doctype = value;});
this.__defineSetter__("apikey", function (value) {return plugin.apikey = value;});

this.Init();

this.getCurrentPosition = function(onSuccess, onError)
{
    if(onError != undefined)
        plugin.GetCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    else
        plugin.GetCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
}

this.setLocation = function(lat, lng, zoom, onSuccess)
{
    onSuccessFeedback = onSuccess;

    plugin.SetLocation(lat, lng, zoom, onSuccess);
}

this.prepare = function(onSuccess, onError)
{
    if(onError != undefined)
        plugin.prepare(onSuccess, onError);
    else
        plugin.prepare(onSuccess);
}
}

try
{
window.__defineGetter__('_altergeo_bho', function() {
    return window.altergeo_bho || (window.altergeo_bho = new __AlterGeo__Chrome_Ext__()) 
});
}catch(e){}
```

Никто с этим не сталкивался? Может кто-нибудь объяснить этот код делает со страницей (вдруг пароли ворует)? :))

Мне очень интересно, почему в плагине файл называется "injected". Особенно на фоне того, что я где-то прочел что на ихнем репозитории завелись "гости".

**UPD:**

Прежде чем смеяться над моими опасениями и минусовать, советую почитать эту статью: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142521/

Comment: какие к черту пароли? Хз что а не вопрос

Comment: @AlexWindHope, своровать пароли таким способом невозможно? Доказательство, PLZ!!))) Черт с ним, с этим вопросом, меня интересует сама идея. Жду ответа.

Comment: Неа, содержимое форм (в т.ч. пароли) таки можно собирать. А вопрос действительно безумный.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вот та статья: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142521/

P.S. Сегодня Mail агент сказал что моя учетка где-то используется (я только со своего компа выхожу). Странно, к чему бы это? Совпадение?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стоит различать слова `injected` и `infected`, нет пароли этот скрипт не воруют, а inject означает внедрение

Comment: Опечатку я заметил, но уже было поздно. Теперь все стало на свои места.